# "Say it simple" or "say it simply"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

I haven't confused myself about an adjective and an adverb in a long time, but this one really got me.

I am trying to say: "Say it, using simple language, with one clear message."
In short:

"Say it simple"

or

"Say it simply"?

My feeling is the latter means, "Just say it", whereas the first one - hopefully - means what I mean.
But as mentioned, I properly confused myself over this one. Or maybe I am just too tired to think straight... ;)

Comment: Are you thinking of "**Keep** it simple"? "Simply say it" does mean "just say it." "Say it simply" doesn't.

Comment: Yes, like keep it simple, which funnily enough, I am using in the same paragraph. So why is it "keep it simple", but "say it simply" then? Isn't the simple in "keep it simple" also referring to the verb?

Answer (score 1):

You need the second version

> "Say it simply"

**Say** is the verb and how you say it is the adverb, **simply**.
"Say it simple" doesn't really work in BrE except that is some contexts it could be interpreted as a derogatory command "Say it [you] simple [person]"

Comment: Thank you, that is interesting. And makes sense, even if I still feel a slight inner resistance towards this one - for whichever reason! "Say it simply" it is then. :)